# Google maps location in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I am using [Autocompleate](http://ngmodules.org/modules/ngAutocomplete) model, to get locations when typing. When I pass that info to Google maps, it doesnt show the location, but if i manually put inside `center="London street"` it shows. What could be the problem here?

```
 <div class="form-group move-down">
        <label for="Autocomplete">Generic Autocomplete</label>
            <input ng-model="result1" type="text" id="Autocomplete" class="form-control" ng-autocomplete="result1" details="details1" options="options1"/>
    </div>


 <map style="display:block;height:300px" center="result1" zoom="15" >   <marker position="result1" /></map>

 <pre>{{result1}}</pre>
```

result 1 shows like `Märkverk & Tyger, Visby, Sweden`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know google maps but shouldnt result1 have bind brackets round it in the map element